# Transferring data by select criteria in multiple columns in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a roster file that I want to select managers employee data from (employee name, ID, salary, etc...), to transfer to a new excel workbook and save under their name. Managers names are column A. I only want to select a few of the data to transfer to their own workbook, so I made a Setup worksheet with the managers names I want in column A.

Code:

```
    Sub Main()
      Dim Managers, Manager
      Dim Header As Range, Where As Range, This As Range
      Dim Wb As Workbook

      'Prepare
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False

      'Refer to the headings
      Set Header = Range("A1").EntireRow
      'Refer to the data in column A
      Set Where = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      'Get the managers
      With Worksheets("Setup")
        Set Managers = .Range("A", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      End With
      'Loop through
      For Each Manager In Managers
        'Find them
        Set This = FindAll(Where, Manager)
        If This Is Nothing Then GoTo Skip
        'Create a new file
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
        With Wb
          With .Sheets(1)
            'Copy the header
            Header.Copy .Range("A1")
            'Copy the data
            This.EntireRow.Copy .Range("A2")
          End With
          'Save it
          .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Manager & "_Roster.xlsx", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
          .Close
        End With
        Skip:
            Next
            'Done
    End Sub
```

I keep getting an application-defined error on this line:

```
Set Managers = .Range("A", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

Can anyone help me debug this?

If anyone needs dummy data for reference, you can just do this:

in a blank worksheet make headers that read (manager, employee, employee ID, salary)

put in cells (A2=manager 1, A3=manager 2, A4=manager 3, A5=manager 4), copy and paste those so you get a bunch of repeating blocks of those.

B2=employee 1 and then you can drag down to fill series to last cell in column A, and just do the same for columns C and D.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXCus.jpg

Then, label a new worksheet "Setup" and in A1=manager 1 and A2= manager 3. This should set you up enough to test the script I've provided. It should reference the Setup sheet and only pull data from manager 1 into a workbook and then manager 3 into a workbook without touching manager 2 or 4's data.

like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbv5v.jpg

and if it works properly I would like it to look like this for both managers data in a new workbook and look like this:

https://imgur.com/a/4zfglUa

Let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: your last link doesn't work but photos are not ideal.  Text is much easier for others to read and work with in trying to help you. You can use a site like [**ASCII Table Generator**](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) (on compact mode) to easily format Excel tables etc into a way that can be pasted into the post body

Comment: are you sure the error arises from `Set Where = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`? I'd never say why

Comment: @bloomfieldhero9219: `Set Where = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` doesn't give an error even if column A is empty...

Comment: @bloomfieldhero9219: this line **would give an error**: `Set where = .Range("A", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` as you have to give a starting reference

Comment: @ashleedawg 

my apologies, the error is here

    Set Managers = .Range("A", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Comment: @OurManinBananas

error is here, my apologies

    Set Managers = .Range("A", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Comment: @bloomfieldhero9219: change `.Range("A", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) ` to `.Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`

Comment: @OurManinBananas OMG THANK YOU!!!!!! wow what a small error, one last thing. What could I add to the code in order to have it unwrap text? It seems to automatically wrap the text, but I want it fit normal and resized to autofit

Comment: @bloomfieldhero9219: to resize columns, you can use something like `range("A:A").entirecolumn.autofit` - anytime you need some help, firstly try recording a macro and looking at the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is

```
Set Managers = .Range("A", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

change it to

```
Set Managers = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```